# Checking for environment CRC in u-boot script

Tags: u-boot

When I bring up my fresh out of the press system, u-boot comes with default environment (that I fine-crafted when compiling u-boot.
That is expected.

`Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment`

However, to automate deployment I would like to do `saveenv` to initialize the environment in MMC but would like to do it *only* when there is no valid environment in the storage.

I am looking for a way to determine whether the environment has a bad CRC (such as uninitialized) and initialize it with the default using `savenev`.
Once I initialize the environment I can further automate settings (such as `ethaddr`) from my deployment shell script using fw_setenv.

I didn't find a way how to do it programmatically within the u-boot script.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant solution but at least I have a working workaround:

I added a script that is checking if a specific environment variable `env_written` serving as a flag is set. If not, the script creates (sets) the flag and performs `saveenv`.
The flag variable makes sure the script runs only once and not at future boots.

```
setenv init_env "if test -n '"$env_written"'; then ; else env default -a; setenv env_written 1; echo '"... inaugural saveenv"'; saveenv; fi"
```

Lastly I added an invocation of this script in the `bootcmd` script that is always executed.

```
setenv bootcmd "run init_env; echo '"bootcmd: "'; run loadfpga; bridge enable; run distro_bootcmd"
```

It does the job :-)

For reference - below is the encoding suitable for copy-pasting to your `config_distro_bootcmd.h` if you want to get this behavior *out of the box*:

```
"init_env="                               \
"if test -n \"$env_written\"; then ; "    \
"else "                                   \
   "env default -a; "                     \
   "setenv env_written 1; "               \
   "echo \"... inaugural saveenv\"; "     \
   "saveenv; "                            \
"fi;\0"
```

and

```
#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND "run init_env; echo \"bootcmd: \"; run loadfpga; bridge enable; run distro_bootcmd"
```

Enjoy better scripting possibilities!

Edit:
Adding suggestion from @ngc6027 to the code above (Thanks!)

Comment: In order to protect the environment in case an unknown environment is loaded instead of the default one, you may want to consider adding 'env default -a' to the beginning of the 'else' case. I've had some odd problems on my boards where a valid u-boot environment is found and loaded, but I don't know where it came from. In these cases, the special 'env_written' variable won't be set, but you'll ensure what you're saving is the default environment and not a slightly modified unknown environment.

Comment: @ngc6027 Great idea! Thanks!